# Bitmasks to check who has access

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have a few pages which contains access bitmasks, which restrict access only to given users. Every user has his own access bitmask, which is used to compare with page bitmask.

For example, I have following page and user bitmasks:

```
USER 0100
PAGE 0101
```

To check if user has access to a page, I perform bitwise AND operation between page and user access code. If result of such operation equals to user bitmask, then access is granted.

```
USER & PAGE == USER   <--- ACCESS OK
USER & PAGE != USER   <--- NO ACCESS
```

For the example above:

```
0100 & 0101 == 0100   <--- ACCESS OK
```

My solution was working great until I have created a user with wider access:

```
USER 1100
PAGE 0101

1100 & 0101 = 0100   <--- NO ACCESS
```

The additional bit in user's bitmask ruins my access verification method. How can I fix it?

To grant access, at least one bit must return "true" for AND operation between USER and PAGE bitmasks.

Comment: `To grant access, at least one bit must return "true" for AND operation between USER and PAGE bitmasks.`  Isn't your earlier statement about USER & PAGE == USER <--- ACESS OK wrong then?

Comment: The problem with this formula is when user has more privileges, it makes the formula to be false. In example 0100 & 0101 = 0100 (OK), 1100 & 0101 = 0100 (FALSE)

Comment: I found the answer for this problem. If at least one bit has to be matched, I can just check if result of the formula is larger or equal than 1:

   USER & PAGE >= 1

This way, the formula will be true if at least one bit will match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this problem. If at least one bit has to be matched, I can just check if result of the formula is larger or equal than 1: USER & PAGE >= 1 This way, the formula will be true if at least one bit will match.